# Does Elasticsearch stream results?

Tags: elasticsearch

Does Elasticsearch stream the query results as they are "calculated" or does it calculate everything and then return the final response back to the client?

Comment: I figure not since it needs to build the full json response before it can respond back with any bytes to the client.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default elasticsearch will only return a limited set of results for a query. (i.e. searching for * will only return the default count set regardless of the number of matches).

Generally to implement "streaming" , you make an initial search to get total count of matching documents and then ask for documents in ranges ( i.e. first 10, next 10, etc.. )

See

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html

for how to request the number of documents returned.

Comment: Interesting so if I want to return a very large result say with 300000 documents then I can make 300 requests of 1000 documents each. So from :0, size: 1000 - from: 1000, size 1000 - from: 2000, size 1000 and so on right? How do I know I'm at the last page?

Comment: Ok I just tried it if you go past the last page it returns no results. So question would this be the right way to export large results for a "report" type system? I'm not talking about frond end? I'm talking about a back end application that will execute a custom query and build a file with 300000 + results.

Comment: I'm upvoting this. But if there a better way to query and export 300,000 docs it would be nice to know. Btw I know about scan search_type. But order matters.

Comment: If the intent is to export a snapshot of the data, you would probably want to use the scroll search option. Once you start your scroll, your  results will not be impacted by current indexing operations.

Comment: Good choice also. Though it's required that data be sorted. So scan/scroll is out. I can mitigate the "data changing" issue with a "closed date/time".

Comment: Though I suspect scrolling also requires more memory too? I suppose also that scroll can be used without scan which then allows me to sort again?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried scroll query?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html  much easier to deal with than pagination.

> Scrolling is not intended for real time user requests, but rather for processing large amounts of data, e.g. in order to reindex the contents of one index into a new index with a different configuration.

Comment: it's definitely a good API for large amount of doc retrieving.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the question in the comments:

> So question would this be the right way to export large results for a
>   "report" type system? I'm not talking about frond end? I'm talking
>   about a back end application that will execute a custom query and
>   build a file with 300000 + result

I'm sure there might be a valid reasons for doing this, but to me it sounds like you're using a hammer to drive screws. Much of the point of using elasticsearch is to use it's aggregations features to do more of the computing in the data store.

[Aggregations Documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html)

If you really need the raw data of 300000 records, then thats what you need. However, if it's a report, that implies you're doing some manipulation of the data into metrics. Much of the point of ES is that it allows you to build "custom reports" on the fly. I suspect it will be much faster to put as much logic as you can into the query, rather simply manipulating the raw data.

Without knowing more about the requirements, I can't come up with any better answer than that.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. It's part of a larger reporting system. But the idea is to run a speficic query and export those 300,000+ docs. Pagination can be a good idea. Just wondering if there's better ways.

Answer (score 1):

No, Elastic so far does not support this. The Elastic API uses a traditional request/response model. The query results are paginated, buffered on the server-side, and sent back to the client. A truly read of the response body in a streaming fashion does not seem to be in the Elastic roadmap.

With that said, for big result sets the scroll API has been deprecated and was never intended for real-time user queries. At the moment the best option is the [search_after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) that could be seen as a cursor in traditional RDBMS.